# bootstrap 5 on rails 6 (justify-content-center)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie here, please avoid complex answers :)

A row was created to center all of its content, it worked just fine. The form submit button and the link_to "Cancel and return to articles listing" are not being centered, even though it is within the row. I even wiped my application.scss stylesheet incase something was conflicting.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-10">
            <%= form_with(model: @article, local: true) do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <%= f.label :title, class: "col-2 col-form-label" %>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <%= f.label :description, class: "col-2 col-form-label" %></br>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-outline-light btn-lg w-25 mt-4" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <%= link_to "Cancel and return to articles listing", articles_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14D4m.png)

Comment: afaik, the `link_to` need to be inside its own `row` (it cant be sibling of a `col-10`). then you could add `justify-content-center` on the new `row`.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, that did the trick. Do you know why link_to has this limitation?

Comment: its not the `link_to` limitation, its twitter bootstrap thing. when you have a `row`, you must have at least one `col` inside - thats why we have `col-sm-12` to represent a column that spans entire row.